# macOS SearchKit CoreService found nothing

Tags: xcode, macos, core-services, searchkit

im working on an that search in the content of allot of files, i planed to use [SearchKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SearchKitConcepts/searchKit_intro/searchKit_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002842-TPXREF101) but i can't figure out to make Apple's sample code to work, and i can't find any other ressources (NSHipster code didn't work either), here's my code:

```
#define kSearchMax 1000

@interface ViewController()
@property(nonatomic) SKIndexRef mySKIndex;
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize mySKIndex;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        [self openIndex];
        [self addDoc];

        SKIndexFlush(self.mySKIndex);

//      i thought that the indexation may need some time ..
        sleep(2);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self searchterm:@"var"];
        });
    });
}


- (void) openIndex {
    NSString *path = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"index"] stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"txt"];      // 1
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    NSString *name = @"extension_index";
    if ([name length] == 0) name = nil;

    SKIndexType type = kSKIndexInverted;

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
        mySKIndex = SKIndexOpenWithURL ((__bridge CFURLRef) url,
                                        (__bridge CFStringRef) name,
                                        true
                                        );
    }else{
        self.mySKIndex = SKIndexCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef) url,
                                              (__bridge CFStringRef) name,
                                              (SKIndexType) type,
                                              (CFDictionaryRef) NULL);
    }
}


- (void) addDoc {
    SKLoadDefaultExtractorPlugIns ();

    NSString *path = [NSBundle.mainBundle pathForResource:@"Products" ofType:@"rtf"];  // 1
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path];          // 2
    SKDocumentRef doc = SKDocumentCreateWithURL ((__bridge CFURLRef) url);
    NSString *mimeTypeHint = @"text/rtf";
    BOOL added = SKIndexAddDocument ((SKIndexRef) mySKIndex,
                                        (SKDocumentRef) doc,
                                        (__bridge CFStringRef)mimeTypeHint,
                                        (Boolean) true
                                        );
    NSLog(added ? @"added" : @"not added");
}

- (void) searchterm:(NSString*)query{
    SKSearchOptions options = kSKSearchOptionDefault;
    BOOL more = YES;
    UInt32 totalCount = 0;
    SKSearchRef search = SKSearchCreate (mySKIndex,
                                         (__bridge CFStringRef) query,
                                         options);
    while (more) {
        SKDocumentID    foundDocIDs [kSearchMax];
        float           foundScores [kSearchMax];
        float *scores;
        Boolean unranked =
        options & kSKSearchOptionNoRelevanceScores;

        if (unranked) {
            scores = NULL;
        } else {
            scores = foundScores;
        }

        CFIndex foundCount = 0;
        more = SKSearchFindMatches (
                                    search,
                                    kSearchMax,
                                    foundDocIDs,
                                    scores,
                                    100,
                                    &foundCount
                                    );
        NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"current count = %i", totalCount]);
        totalCount += foundCount;
    }
}
@end
```

it always print "current count = 0" and the loop is executed only one time.

Comment: Documentation: [Search Kit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/search_kit). The link you posted is to an old version from 2005 in the Documentation archive. It says: "Important: This document is no longer being updated. For the latest information about Apple SDKs, visit the documentation website".

Comment: Now I am into the same problem. No valid sample that works and is up-to-date. I create index, but no terms generated inside. Zero. So no search results. @RedMak, have you finally managed to get it working?

Comment: Wow! I've just added a call to `SKLoadDefaultExtractorPlugIns();` on the app launch and that solved the problem. Now I have terms filled up. The search results are somewhat weird, but will try to figure out that too.